# Python says that a float number is an integer

Tags: python

I was writing a program to check and print if a number is integer or float and it usually works great.
But when I try some value like 2.0000000000000001 I get the message it is an integer, why?

Code:

```
import math

number = float(input("Enter a number: "))

if number == round(number):
    print("Integer number")
else:
    print("Float number")
```

Comment: What do you see if you print this float number?  And what do you know about *round-off error*?

Comment: Related, at the very least: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/10077

Comment: The question is natural enough, so I don't think that the downvotes are deserved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: For testing for float vs. int input, wouldn't be more reliable to use: s = input("Enter a number: "); if '.' in s: print('number is float') else: print('numer is int').

Comment: Darryl, what about inputs like `4e-2` or `13e4`. Both are definitely floats

Comment: As an aside, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a "float" is. Floating point is a way to represent *real numbers*. So, mathematical *integers* may be represented as floats as well. It is a *data type*. Both the `int` and the `float` data type can represent mathematical integers. My point is simply to keep the computing concept separate from the pure mathematics concept.

Answer (score 1):

In a float, a portion of the storage bits is used to specify the number and the remaining bits are used to determine the power. My guess is that the amount of bits needed to create the number 20000000000000001 is higher thant the available amount.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking whether it is `float`, or `integer`, you are checking whether the `number` is equal to `round(number)`, and due to the imprecision in the storage of floating point numbers, they WILL be equal for such small differences.
If you want to check whether it is an `integer` or `float`, try this:

```
number = float(input("Enter a number: "))

if type(number) == int:
    print("Integer number")
elif type(number) == float:
    print("Float number")
```

Of course this will always print "Float number", since `number` is a `float`, doesn't matter if your input was `2` or `2.5` (`2` will be stored as `2.0`).

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the floating number " 2.0000000000000001" you'll see that you'll get 2.0. This is because in Python, you can't truly achieve floating precision, as described in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Therefore, in your conditional statement, rounding 2.0 will get you 2, which is equal to 2.0.

It's still a floating point, because if you do type(number), you'll see that it belongs to a class of float.

Comment: It is incorrect to say that _"in Python, you can't truly achieve floating precision"_. Python gives you IEEE-754 standard floating point numbers, the exact same as other languages, like C or Java and exactly the same as what your CPU supports. And those floating point numbers have a limitation on their precision, by design.